# How to use map() for editing object elements inside array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
const data = [
  { name: "Santa"
    age: 34
  },
  { name: "John"
    age: 23
  }
]
```

I should edit object elements through `map()`.
For example: I want all *age* to be 68 and 46 relatively. (×2).

I tried to solve but I couldn't

```
data = data.map(e => {
      e.age *= 2;
});
```

Comment: Just in case it matters, your attempt was mutating source array and returned `age` properties ***only***. So, more conventional use of `map()` would be something immutable, like [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60936346/11299053).

Comment: for mutating approach, you may replace `map()` with `forEach()` and get your problem solved with *more appropriate tool*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use a return statement, also use `let` because your data is not in fact constant:

```js
let data = [{
    name: "Santa",
    age: 34
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 23
  }
]

data = data.map(e => {e.age *= 2; return e;});
console.log(data)
```

Comment: It sure does but OP asks for *editing objects inside array*, favoring mutation

Answer (score 1):

The map function replaces the value in the array with the result returned by your lambda function (in your case your arrow function). 
Always make sure you return a value ;)

```
data = data.map(e => {
      return {..e, age: e.age * 2};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Santa", age: 34 },
  { name: "John", age: 23 }
];
console.log( data.map( item => ({
  ...item,
  age: item.age + 10 // modify here
})))
data.forEach( item => {
  item.age = item.age + 10 // modify direct object
})
console.log( data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic will be correct if you `return e;`

```
data = data.map(e =>{e.age *= 2; return e})
```

```js
let data = [
  { name: "Santa",
    age: 34
  },
  { name: "John",
    age: 23
  }
]

data = data.map(e =>{e.age *= 2; return e})
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `map()` function, alter the age property of each object, then return the entire object:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Santa",
    age: 34
  },
  { name: "John",
    age: 23
  }
]

let resp = data.map(obj => {
      obj.age *= 2
      return obj
});

console.log(resp)
```

Answer (score 1):

two small mistakes: 1) you need to place ',' after object values and you need a return

```js
var data = [
  { name: "Santa",
    age: 34
  },
  { name: "John",
    age: 23
  }
]

 data.map(e=> {
      e.age *= 2;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: updated to include entire array with new values for age

Answer (score 0):

Try with **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map)**

```js
const data = [ { name: "Santa", age: 34 }, { name: "John", age: 23 }]
   
console.log(data.map(res=>({...res, age: res.age*2})))
```